# Transform a trapezium into a rectangle

Tags: software-rec, images, editing, processing

I used my iPhone to capture a painting. However, the angle was not perfect, so instead of getting a straight rectangle, I get a trapezium. I want to transform this trapezium back into a rectangle (using some affine transformation). However, I cannot find a good way to do it. Please advise.

Comment: My guest would be I can select four points in the captured photo and define the other 4 points of the rectangle and have the software transform it for me based on the coordinates of these points. However, I cannot figure out how to do that with GIMP

Comment: As in the dupe - have a look at Imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GIMP, it is called the perspective tool.  I think it is the same in Photoshop.

There is an icon for it in the menu on the left.  It looks like a trapezoid with two arrows at the bottom corners.

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick gives you the [`-distort Perspective`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#distort) option. Like explained in [Perspective Distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective):

> convert image.jpg -distort Perspective '7,4 4,3   4,1 4,1   85,1 100,1   85,2 100,3' result.jpg

Answer (score 4):

[paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) will do this - you're looking for the 'layers', 'rotate/zoom' option. just move the ball to get it aligned

Answer (score 2):

I know there already is an accepted answer, but [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) that can also be used to fix perspectives in pictures, and is much better at it than a regular photo editing software. There is [a tutorial](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml) on their website explaining how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. This software is amazing. It deserves to be an answer, though.