# Keystone correct an image

Tags: software-rec, image-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [transform a trapezium into a rectangle](https://superuser.com/questions/117742/transform-a-trapezium-into-a-rectangle)

I have taken a picture of a piece of paper (standard letter-sized) with a camera.  But I was not able to perfectly position the camera, so the picture of the piece shows up as a trapezoid.  Are there any free or inexpensive tools that can correct this type of error easily.

I do know the full version of photo shop can do this, but this is something I very rarely need, I am not interested in selling a kidney to fix this image.

Comment: @Linker3000, thanks for pointing me at the duplicate.  I guess I was searching with the incorrect terms.